# Can't render some NG-ZORRO icon

Tags: angular, antd, ant-design-pro, ng-zorro-antd

As described in the title, some of the icons from NG-ZORRO can't be rendered.

Expected 5 icons to be rendered, however only 2 were rendered.

View attached for the output

main.component.html

```
<nz-layout class="full-screen">
    <nz-sider nzCollapsible
              [(nzCollapsed)]="isCollapsed"
              [nzWidth]="260">
        <app-left-control></app-left-control>
    </nz-sider>
    <nz-content class="container">
        <i nz-icon nzType="step-backward" nzTheme="outline"></i> Cannot render<br>
        <i nz-icon nzType="down" nzTheme="outline"></i> Can render<br>
        <i nz-icon nzType="caret-left" nzTheme="outline"></i> Cannot render<br>
        <i nz-icon nzType="double-right" nzTheme="outline"></i> Can render<br>
        <i nz-icon nzType="setting" nzTheme="outline"></i> Cannot render<br>
    </nz-content>
</nz-layout>
```

main.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MainComponent } from './main.component';

import { MainRoutingModule } from './main-routing.module';
import { NzLayoutModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/layout';
import { NzButtonModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/button';
import { NzIconModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/icon';

import { LeftControlComponent } from './left-control/left-control.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MainComponent,
    LeftControlComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MainRoutingModule,
    NzLayoutModule,
    NzButtonModule,
    NzIconModule,
  ]
})
export class MainModule { }
```

Output

[image: Ouput of main.component.html]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [NG-ZORRO Static loading and dynamic loading](https://ng.ant.design/components/icon/en#static-loading-and-dynamic-loading), you should follow these steps to display those missing icons.

### Pre-requisite:

```
npm install @ant-design/icons-angular
```

### Step 1: Dynamic importing via angular.json

> angular.json

```
{
  "assets": [
    {
      "glob": "**/*",
      "input": "./node_modules/@ant-design/icons-angular/src/inline-svg/",
      "output": "/assets/"
    }
  ]
}
```

### Step 2: Add Icons in Lazy-loaded Modules

> main.module.ts

```
import {
  StepBackwardOutline,
  CaretLeftOutline,
  SettingOutline
} from '@ant-design/icons-angular/icons';

const icons: IconDefinition[] = [
  StepBackwardOutline,
  CaretLeftOutline,
  SettingOutline
];

export class MainModule {
  ...
  imports: [
    NzIconModule.forChild(icons),
  ]
}
```

Note:

1. How do I know a icon's corresponding module to import?

> Capital camel-case type & theme, i.e. alibaba => AlibabaOutline.

[Sample solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zqj76n?file=src/app/icon.module.ts)

---

### Updated for Post Owner's comment

These two icons `DownOutline` and `DoubleRightOutline` are not required to be imported as these icons have been imported by [default](https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/blob/master/components/icon/icons.ts).

---

### Reference(s)

1. [ERROR Error: [@ant-design/icons-angular]: the icon arrow-left-o does not exist or is not registered.](https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/issues/3389#issuecomment-536235224)
2. [Add Icons in Lazy-loaded Modules](https://ng.ant.design/components/icon/en#add-icons-in-lazy-loaded-modules)
3. [How do I know a icon's corresponding module to import?](https://ng.ant.design/components/icon/en#add-icons-in-lazy-loaded-modules)

Comment: it was very helpful, may i ask why do the two icons rendered successful dont need to be imported?

Comment: Update to your comment. The reason why those 2 icons are not needed import as [`DownOutline` & `DoubleRightOutline` are imported by default](https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/blob/master/components/icon/icons.ts). You may upvote/mark this as the correct answer if this helps you. Thank you.